# Azure Data Factory V2 - Calling a stored procedure that returns multiple result set

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to create an ADF v2 pipeline that calls a stored procedure in Azure SQL Database. The stored procedure has input parameters and would return multiple result sets (around 3). We need to get it extracted. We are trying to load to Blob storage of 4 different files or load to table.

Is there a way to perform in pipeline?

In SSIS there is option to use script component and extract. https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2015/04/27/the-ssis-object-variable-and-multiple-result-sets/

Looking for suggestions in Data factory.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot easily accomplish that in Azure Data Factory (ADF) as the Stored Procedure activity does not support resultsets at all and the Copy activity does not support multiple resultsets.  However with a few small changes you could get the same outcome: you have a couple of options:

1. If the code and SSIS package already exist and you want to minimise your refactoring, you could host it in ADF via the SSIS-IR
2. *Maybe* you could accomplish this with an Azure Function which are kind of roughly equivalent to the SSIS Script Tasks, but it seems like a bit of a waste of time to me.  It's an unproven pattern and you have simpler options such as:
3. Break the stored proc into parts: have it process its data and not return any resultsets.  Alter the proc to place the three resultsets in tables instead.  Have multiple Copy activities which will run in parallel, copy the data to blob store after the main Stored Proc activity has finished, something like this:

[image: ADF Pipeline]

It's also possible to trick the Lookup activity to run stored procedures for you but the outputs are limited to 5,000 rows and it's not like you can pipe it into a Copy activity afterwards.  I would recommend option 3 which will get the same outcome with only a few changes to your proc.

Comment: We went with adding additional parameter to stored procedure to return one table based on the param

Comment: As long as the proc does not reprocess the same data three times, which would be a waste of resources.